# Coordination of two trackBars

Tags: c#, trackbar

I have two trackBars and I want to that when I move one of them, the other one also is moved in the same time.

If it is possible, how can I do that?

Comment: Of course it is possible. Handle the appropriate event on both trackbars. When the event is raised, set the other trackbar's position.

Comment: Decide if this shall work one or two-way! In the latter case you'll need a flag to avoid a loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the ValueChanged event of the First trackbar. On the trigger of thatevent, update the second track bar with the corresponding value.